# How to add a new string to a *.po file w/ a PO editor

Tags: translation, gettext, poedit

I MANUALLY created a file: test.po with the contents:

> msgid "greeting"
>   msgstr "Hello World"

Now I can edit the translation (hello world) in editors like "poedit" and "GTranslated" (I'm using Ubuntu). I can even add comments to that translation. However neither "poedit" and "GTranslated" will let me ADD a new translation string - I've looked online to no avail and looked at screenshots of other editors and none seem to have a "new" button.

What am I missing??? It seems stupid to have to edit new keys w/ a "plain" text editor and then edit them in these PO editors (whichever they may be). (If you can't tell I'm new to this 'gettext' world - I'm building a website in Zend/PHP.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should never be adding strings directly to a .po file; they will be [added by `msgmerge` from the .pot file generated by `xgettext`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Overview).

Comment: I have a scenario, where I needs to add two words only into PO file, for that opening and re-generating PO files seems a little long way, don't you think?

Comment: @iamtheladylegend: Editing by hand is not automatable.

Comment: I have a case where I am adding words with %s for strings with link between ex. <a href="somelink">Link Name</a> and currency data with %d ex. $123.00 while a string which have multiple links in single word, are entered like, %1$s and %2$s for ex. Hello <a href="#">Link1</a>. You are <a href="#">Link2</a> welcome now. Now, above words like %1$s and %2$s are not included in PO files, any idea why?

Comment: What if the source of my strings is in a database for example. How do I get the messages to be made then in the po file? Compilemssage seems to ignore everything not previously grabbed by makemessage

Answer (score 13):

Here's what I did:

Edit the .po file and add your new string, for example:

```
msgid "All Catalogues"
msgstr "Todos los catalogos"
```

Save the .po file.

Now open it in **poedit** and in the menu select: Catalog > Update from POT file

Once you've updated you should see the new string and will be able to change it.

Save changes and you're good to go.

Comment: My use case might be slightly different since I *am* using a POT file.  Regardless, your answer still helped me.  To add a new translation manually, I added the code you specified to the **POT file**, and then opened my .po translation in poedit and selected Catalog > Update from POT as you suggested.  Worked perfectly.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear @rinogo

Answer (score 5):

MacOS:

1. Edit the .po file in any text editor.
2. Open the .po file in Poedit (free)
3. In Poedit, select file -> Compile to .MO

This is what worked for me in a Wordpress Genesis .po file.

Comment: So all poedit is doing is compiling the .mo file? It seems a bit odd you can't add entries in poedit. I think this is at the root of the OP's puzzlement - it's why I came here.

Comment: @ChrisPink That's how the gettext translation system works. You don't add strings manually, because they come from source code - if something isn't in the code, it makes no sense to translate it, the translation would never be *used*. So instead of doing all that manually, you automatically extract all texts to translate from the code.

Comment: @Václav Slavík How do you do this in a Wordpress environment (with Polylang)?

Answer (score 1):

open the .po file with any text editor, add these line or what ever the text need to added.

```
msgid "All Catalogues"
msgstr "Todos los catalogos"
```

save and launch :-D

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but I found myself wanting to translate strings that are stored in the WordPress database and not translatable with Polylang.

What I did was creating a PHP file in the theme and I added strings with `__("A string to translate");`
The PoEdit automatically added it to the .po file.